# Power Query null issues

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to create a custom column in power query that counts null values from column 7 - column 41. The function I have used is  List.NonNullCount(List.Range(Record.FieldValues(*),7,41))). There are many many rows of data so I would like it to calculate each row within the custom column.
For some reason even though each column between 7-41 has null values across the row the output is 2. I would expect the output to be 0. Futhermore I am getting an output of 35 when all columns from 7-41 have a value not equal to null across the row. I would expect 34 in this case. I did replace all blank values with null using the transform function in power query.
I'm not sure if my function List.NonNullCount(List.Range(Record.FieldValues(*),7,41))) is correct or if there is a better way to do it. any help appreciated!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my version, you need to have an argument for `Record.FieldValues`.  What you write: `Record.FieldValues()` would produce an error.

Also, the third argument of `List.Range` is the number of columns to return; it is **not** the number of the **last** column.

And the first column is column `0`, not column `1`

So something like:

```
List.NonNullCount(List.Range(Record.FieldValues(_),6,35))
```

should return the nonNull count for columns 7-41

Comment: Thank you so much, worked perfectly.. Apologies regarding (_) I must have deleted somehow when copying over.